# Cannot grant read-only GCR access to GCE instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform, google-container-registry, terraform-provider-gcp

I have:

- a service account
- a GCE instance using that service 
  account
- a container image uploaded to GCR

I cannot seem to grant read-only GCR access to that instance. All resources are in the same project. I have tried granting the `storage.admin` and `storage.objectViewer` roles to the service account, and in each case accessing the container registry results in `https://eu.gcr.io/v2/<project>/<image>/manifests/latest: 401 Unauthorized`.

All documentation I've read says I need the `storage-rw` scope and `storage.objectViewer` granted on the bucket for GCR in that region, all of which I have.

I'm configuring all this with Terraform. How have you configured GCR access to a service account using Terraform?

Here's my code:

```
locals {
  gcr-region = "eu"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
    account_id = "k3s-master"
    display_name = "k3s-master"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
    name = "${var.service_name}"
    machine_type = "f1-micro"

    allow_stopping_for_update = true

    service_account {
        email = "${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
        scopes = [
            "storage-rw",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
        ]
    }

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "debian-9"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "${google_compute_network.k3s-network.self_link}"
        access_config { }
    }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_binding" "eu-binding" {
  bucket     = "eu.artifacts.${var.project}.appspot.com"
  role        = "roles/storage.objectViewer"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}",
  ]
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_binding" "binding" {
  bucket     = "${var.project}.appspot.com"
  role        = "roles/storage.objectViewer"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, this turned out to be something else entirely.

To debug further I used `curl` and `gsutil` from the compute instance and found that I *could* access the underlying buckets.

I am running `k3s` on the instance involved and **this needs to be explicitly configured to use the service account to authenticate to GCR** (even though the compute instance is running under the same service account, this is still required).

Thus, a `kubectl create secret docker-registry ...` followed by setting `imagePullSecrets` for the (kubernetes) service account I'm using fixed it. [More details about that here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file).